# Bean validation on REST API input, and API versioning

Tags: java, api, rest, bean-validation

I have a bean like:

```
  @Data
  public static class ClassUnderTest {
    @NotNull
    private String field1;

    @NotNull
    @Since(2.0)
    private String field2;

    @NotNull
    @Until(3.0)
    private String field3;
  }
```

`@Since` and `@Until` are Gson annotations that permits to avoid serializing / deserializing some fields on my REST API, for certain API versions.

I perform bean validation on the input payload of this API to raise constraint violations.
I'd like to be able to not raise the same violations per version, based on the Gson annotations (and not groups!).

---

Is there a way, from a `ConstraintViolation<T>`, to get the `Member` (like `Method` / `Field`) which produced the violation, so that I check if it is annotated by something?

Is there a way to handle validation versionning with Bean Validation?

The only solution I have seems to retrieve that member from the path (`getPropertyPath`), but it seems not easy to do...

Answer (score 0):

You could retrieve the property name from the violation via `getPropertyPath()`. That said, assigning your constraints to groups corresponding to the versions might be the better approach. Note that validation groups can also extend existing groups, this might be helpful to model constraints added in a newer version.